# shell script source behaviour

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell script. I have a shell script which sources another file. Another file is just a file with name value pair. I have a confusion here.

```
test.dat
TEST_VARIABLE_PATH=/usr/project/workspace
```

script file (test_script.sh)

```
TEST_VARIABLE_PATH=
source test.dat
echo ${TEST_VARIABLE_PATH}
```

The above echo statement prints different values which makes me confused.
In line 1, if I make

```
TEST_VARIABLE_PATH=/somepath/
```

, even I have sourced test.dat which has TEST_VARIABLE_PATH variable already set, echo is printing only

```
TEST_VARIABLE_PATH=/somepath/
```

where sourcing the file did not overwrite the variable.

Suppose If I have the line 1 as

```
TEST_VARIABLE_PATH=\`dirname $0\`/../
```

, source command overwrites and echo prints

```
TEST_VARIABLE_PATH=/usr/project/workspace
```

Why is this source behaving differently ? Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't really `source` the file.

To do it properly, put the *full path* of the file, like :

```
source '/full/path/to/file'
```

Comment: Or just `. /path/to/file`. Notice that it is `dot[space]/path/to/file`